# Role vs tenant in asp.net boilerplate

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I found ASP.NET Boilerplate has supported role and tenant design. However, I am not very sure the difference between these two concepts. Could anyone explain this for me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a university wants a solution in such a way that each of its school manage their staff & students. This can be solved by any multi-tenant application. 
University will be host and schools under it will be its tenants. Each school has its own users who have different roles (instructor, student, admin etc.).

Comment: Thank very much for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

In real world, tenant would be a company. There are different companies out there, each with its own rules and employees. Each employee have its own position in the company (thats the "roles" in this situation).

So group of users will be under one tenant. Inside, each of them will have certain role.

Comment: Thank very much for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Multi-tenancy is used to build SaaS (Software as a Service)
>   applications easily. With this technique, we can deploy single
>   application to serve to multiple customers. Each Tenant will have it's
>   own roles, users and settings.

Source: [Multi Tenancy](https://www.aspnetzero.com/Documents/Development-Guide-Core#multi-tenancy)